# How do I renew an access token in a client app?

Tags: beatsmusic

I've got my Javascript client app working well, but the streaming access token expires after 1 hour. I'm trying to make it play a playlist all the way through, which is often longer than 1 hour. Is there a way to renew the token without requiring the user to log in again?

Answer (score 2):

Client-side applications cannot renew their token as they are not supplied with a refresh token. If you want to renew the token, you need to do a webservice application which can store a secret and use this to renew the access_token.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So there is no way to play > 1 hour of music continually without requiring the user the log in again? Is there some other method that I'm missing?

Comment: Sadly not. I enquired Beats Support about the same issue and the only way is to make a Web Server Application: https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/getting_started/Web_Server_Applications